# Can jQuery fadeIn() add a class instead of an inline style?

Tags: jquery

When running `.fadeIn()` jQuery automatically adds `display:block` inline to the selector:

```
$('div').hide().fadeIn();
```

Is it possible for the result to look like this:

```
<div class="active"></div>
```

Instead of this:

```
<div style="display:block"></div>
```

I don't want to add/remove any inline styles. I can't remove the `style` attribute because there might be styles already set that I do not have control over. I just want to add a class on `fadeIn()` instead of add the inline `display:block` style.

Comment: `$('div').addClass('active');`, then.

Comment: When using `.fadeIn()` jquery automatically adds `display:inline`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try adding the `active` class and clearing the `display` style after `fadeIn()` completes like so:

```
$('div').hide().fadeIn(400, function() {
    $(this).css('display', '').addClass('active');
});
```

Here's a quick example: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yfeaB/)

Comment: Your Fiddle wasn't working for me. But your answer worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will have to use css to initially hide the div, then use transition and opacity to show it.

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWcW3/)</kbd>

**HTML**

```
<div></div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    opacity:0;

    -o-transition: opacity .6s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity .6s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity .6s ease;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .6s ease;
    transition: opacity .6s ease;  

}

div.active {
    opacity:1;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('div').addClass('active');
```

Comment: I do not have access to the external CSS so I cannot manipulate the `.active` CSS. But I like the idea.

Comment: It will work if you inline the css (which I usually dissuadet people from doing).

Comment: Unfortunately, the way this app is set up, I need to do it with jQuery

Comment: But I thought you wanted to add a class? O_o

Comment: Read selected answer from @Divey